# Set different interpreters for specific files in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm working on a Django project that is using Python 3 in a virtualenv. I just came across fabric, which only works under Python 2, so I installed it system wide instead of in my virtualenv (is it even possible to put this in my Python 3 virtualenv, btw?).

The problem here is that I've set PyCharm to use Python 3 as interpreter and having fabric installed for Python 2. When I edit my fabric file it says that all imports from fabric are unknown.

Is there any way I can solve this? Any way to assign my fabric file to use the Python 2 interpreter instead of Python 3, or some other solution?

Comment: Why don't you create a 2.x virtualenv for that project and install what you need in it? PyCharm will do that for you.

Comment: Because everything but the fabric file is in a 3.x virtualenv, so that would break all Python 3 dependencies instead.

Comment: You can't have one file in the project running on a different interpreter to the rest.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson Have you tried to install [Fabric3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3) in command line mode into your 3.x _virtualenv_ , so you ought to run it along?

Answer (score 5):

This is possible to do (at least with the current PyCharm 2018.2.4), but it takes some manual effort and cannot be done through the GUI.

1. Exit PyCharm
2. Navigate to the `.idea` folder of your project
3. Edit `modules.xml`

   - Duplicate the `<module>` line and change the `fileurl` and `filepath` attributes. Mine looked like this when I was done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/dataops.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/dataops.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/dataops_py27.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/dataops_py27.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

4. Copy `$PROJECT_NAME.iml` to the name you gave your new module. In my case I did:
   `cp dataops.iml dataops_py27.iml`
5. Open your project back up in PyCharm and go to `Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter.` You will see the two modules (the initial module and the new one you just created). Select the new one and configure the interpreter by clicking the gear icon in the upper right corner of the window and selecting `Add...`
6. Go to `Preferences > Project > Project Structure.` Make sure your new module is selected, remove the old content root and add a new one.

Note: If you have many files in the folder and do not want the newly added interpreter to apply to all of them you can exclude them in the `Exclude files:` text box located at the bottom of the `Preferences > Project > Project Structure` setting.

Comment: In Pycharm 2018.3, instead of step 1 to 4 above, you can simply do `File > Open` pick the folder where your file is located and then choose "Attach" when prompted on how to open the project. After that you can follow step 5 and 6.